# Action Mailer problems (beginner)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I'm entirely honest, I don't understand action mailers in their entirety and I'm finding it hard to discover a learning resource that isn't using an app which is of a completely different context (e.g teamtreehouses todo app). I would really appreciate a little help.

I have a business directory, I want each listings show page to have a form which when filled in, sends the entered info to the listings attached email.

Here's my code:

Mailers/Enquiry.rb

```
class Enquiry < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "admin@uk-franchise.co.uk"

  def lead(listing, info)
    @listing = listing
    mail(to: @enquiry.email, subject: 'Email Testing Rails App')
    mail(to: @listing.leadrecepient, subject: "test")
  end
end
```

listings controller method

```
  def lead
    info = params[:leadname]
    notifier = Notifier.lead(@listing, info)
  end
```

Routes I'm stuck on configuring as I don't fully understand them for mailers.

What I have in the show listing view so far

```
<%= form_for lead_path(@leadname, @listing), method: :put do |lead| %>
<% end %>
```

Again, if anyone could provide me with a learning resource that would accommodate this scenario or a little help I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you have to do:

- Do not use `mail` method twice in one method

> ```
> class Enquiry < ActionMailer::Base
>   default from: "admin@uk-franchise.co.uk"
>
>   def lead(listing)
>     @listing = listing
>     mail(to: @listing.leadrecepient, subject: "test")
>   end
> end
> ```

- Send your email from within controller action:

> ```
> class ListingsController
>
>   def lead
>     #@listing = Listing...
>     Enquiry.lead(@listing).deliver
>   end
> end
> ```

- routes.rb:

> ```
> # ...
> resources :listings do
>   member do
>     put :lead
>   end
> end
> # ...
> ```

- view:

> ```
> <%= form_for lead_listing_path(@listing), method: :put do |listing| %>
> <% end %>
> ```

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for the help. I am getting a error on the routes code you provided, saying unexpected keyword end. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: C:/Users/Callum/Documents/directory/config/routes.rb:97: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end C:/Users/Callum/Documents/directory/config/routes.rb:168: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end

Comment: Yep, there was a typo in routes.rb, try now

Comment: Thanks, Getting this now: param is missing or the value is empty: listing

Comment: I added this in the form:         <%= listing.text_field :name %>
        <%= listing.submit %>

Comment: Are you using `strong parameters` anywhere? This issue sounds like so

Comment: Yes I do, what should I do mate?

Comment: I'm using strong params for the creation of the listing itself